# Error : /usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1:

Tags: maui, rider

I am using Jetbrains Rider.  I have spent the last 24 hours or so trying to run and debug a maui application on an iPhone.  Everything works on my simulator and my mac.  I have a relatively new mac that I have setup.  Everything works properly in the simulator.  I have set my application id in my .csproj file.  I have my development cert downloaded and installed.  I have created a provisioning profile.  the pp is download.  Questions:

1. in rider's iOS configuration, I can't select a provisioning profile.  I see the pp 3 times.  How do i get rid of these pps?
   Is there a way to see the pps that are setup and being used?
2. the error i get has to do with the codesign error listed all the way at the bottom.  any ideas on this?

I have included the .csproj file portion to show that I have my bundle identifier set.  I have also included the contents of the output window in rider.  I have included that to show details.

TIA.  I know that this is a big ask.  I've googled until i am blue in the face.

```
    <!-- Display name -->
    <ApplicationTitle>BWD</ApplicationTitle>

    <!-- App Identifier -->
    <ApplicationId>com.bwd.app</ApplicationId>
```

Here is a copy of the output from the console build window in rider.  It's too big to paste into here.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvuVPlLxZUtytMhil4Dn32yqyMlqAQ?e=3hrh6Q

Comment: I have gone ahead and deleted my profiles, figured out how to do that.  I now have a slightly different error message:
1>Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): Error  : /usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1:
Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Development: ..."
/Users/...../net core/BWDApps/BWD/bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/BWD.app: errSecInternalComponent

Comment: And here is the second part of the above message:1>Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): Error  : Failed to codesign '/Users/..../net core/BWDApps/BWD/bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/BWD.app': Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Development: ......"
/Users/...../net core/BWDApps/BWD/bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/BWD.app: errSecInternalComponent

Comment: I have tried the instructions here, unfortunately, I fail at codesgin -s "Apple Development" -f "MyTrue"  error: 
MyTrue: replacing existing signature
Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Development: Wallace McClure (GMJV25M3U8)"
MyTrue: errSecInternalComponent

instructions -> https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/712005